# Can I plot a distance matrix/heatmap from a 3 column text file?

Tags: python, r, heatmap

I have several text files which contain distance between two points in three columns. I am trying to plot a distance matrix in 2d or a heatmap but I cant find a function/way to transform my data. Any hints? This is what the data looks like:

```
1 2 3.99
1 3 3.25
1 4 2.77
1 5 3.11
......
2 3 2.99
2 4 8.11
.....
```

Comment: If you're just asking how to make a heatmap from these values: in R using ggplot2, if we call your columns `A`, `B`, and `C` then try `ggplot(data) + geom_tile(aes(A, B, fill = C))`. If that's not your question, please [edit] and provide more details.

Comment: I tried to imagine what your problem could be. It would help to know whether you already imported the data into R (since you wrote your data was a text file, it is not clear whether you already imported it). If so, you could share the data by using the ```dput()``` function any copy the output to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are (as always) multiple options how to reshape the data and how to plot it. Here are some examples. I am making some assumptions regarding your data, though. I tried to imagine your situation. If this solution does not solve the issue, you need to provide more detailed information.

Your data is a matrix(?) like the following:

```
# Note: This is only to create example data of which I suspect it is similar to your original data
data <- cbind(rep(seq(1, 5), each = 5), rep(seq(1, 5), 5), rep(NA, 25))
data <- data[data[, 1] != data[, 2],]
data[, 3] <- runif(NROW(data), min = 0, max = 100)
```

If it is a dataframe, you may skip the next step:

```
# Make it a data.frame
df <- as.data.frame(data)
```

If (and only if) you have not yet managed to read your data in R (you wrote it is a text file?), read it as follows:

```
# Warning: I assume the separator by the way you posted your "example":
df <- read.table("/path/to/your/data.txt", sep = "\t")
```

Now, reshape the data and plot a heatmap:

```
# Name the columns
names(df) <- c("Point1", "Point2", "Distance")
df

# Reshape it to wide data.frame
wide <- reshape(df, v.names = "Distance", idvar = "Point1", timevar = "Point2", direction = "wide")
wide

# Replace non numeric characters in column names to get your integer values as columns
names(wide) <- gsub("[^0-9]", "", names(wide))

# Introduce row names
row.names(wide) <- wide[, 1]

# Remove first column (which is the same as row names)
wide <- wide[, -1]

# Re-order columns so it looks better
wide <- wide[, match(seq(1:ncol(wide)), names(wide))]
wide

# Plot heatmap
heatmap(as.matrix(wide), Rowv = NA, Colv = NA)
```

Another option would be to create a n x n matrix with column and row names identical to the integer IDs of your points. Then, you could use a nested loop to look up the values for each matrix cell. However, this can be very inefficient and it is not advisable to use loops in R with large data sets.

If you want to use ggplot, you do not need to reshape the data to a wide format. Just do as @zephyrl told you:

```
# Alternative
require("ggplot2")
gg <- ggplot(df) + geom_tile(aes(Point1, Point2, fill = Distance))
gg
```